# How to store a list in character type array

Tags: arrays, character

I want to store a list of alphabets in character type array, but some error of hundred lines occurs, which is nearly impossible to read, and I can not find anything what to do, I will provide my code below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
  char alph[]={'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'};

  for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
  {
    cout<<alph[i]<<" ";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there are no non-ASCII characters in your source code (try to paste it into the notepad and the paste it back into the compiler).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
  char alph[]={'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'};

  for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
  {
    cout<<alph[i]<<" ";
  }

  return 0;
}
```